# Process vs OS Networking Synchronization on Linux

Tags: linux, networking

On Linux, when I push say a 10MB packet over a socket… does the process...

A) push the entire packet of data into the operating system, and then move onto other tasks?

or B) feed the 10MB incrementally to the operating system, as requested?

I'm trying to reason about the order in which operations will occur on contentious sockets all managed by the same process.

Comment: This is likely specific to different versions of Linux. I'd use kernel instrumentation on the version(s) of Linux you are interested in to find out.

Comment: @dirkt how do I do that? I'm using Clear Linux.

Comment: https://elinux.org/Kernel_Instrumentation